# python, cv2.imshow(), raspberryPi and a black screen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

Currently trying write code with a GUI which will allow for toggling on/off image processing. Ideally the code will allow for turning on/off window view, real time image processing (pretty basic), and controlling an external board.

The problem I'm having revolves around the `cv2.imshow()` function. A few months back I made a push to increase processing rates by switching from `picamera` to `cv2` where I can perform more complex computations like background subtraction without having to call python all the time. using the **bcm2835-v4l2** package, I was able to pull images directly from the picamera using `cv2`.

fast forward 6 months and while trying to update the code, I find that the function `cv2.imshow()` does not display correctly anymore. I thought it might be a problem with **bcm2835-v4l2** but tests using matplotlib show that the connection is fine. it appears to have everything to do with `cv2.imshow()` or so I guess.

I am actually creating a separate thread using the `threading` module for image capture and I am wondering if this could be the culprit. I don't think so though as typing in the commands

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
grabbed,frame = camera.read()
cv2.imshow(frame)
```

produces the same black screen

Down below is my code I am using (on the RPi3) and some images show the error and what is expected.

as for reference here are the details about my system

```
Raspberry pi3
raspi stretch
python 3.5.1
opencv 3.4.1
```

Code

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread
import time
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Button, Label, mainloop, Tk, RIGHT

class GPIOControllersystem:
    def __init__(self,OutPinOne=22, OutPinTwo=27,Objsize=30,src=0):
        self.Objectsize = Objsize

        # Build GUI controller
        self.TK = Tk()                                                          # Place TK GUI class into self

        # Variables
        self.STSP = 0
        self.ShutdownVar = 0
        self.Abut = []
        self.Bbut = []
        self.Cbut = []
        self.Dbut = []

        # setup pi camera for aquisition
        self.resolution = (640,480)
        self.framerate = 60

        # Video capture parameters
        (w,h) = self.resolution
        self.bytesPerFrame = w * h

        self.Camera = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

    def Testpins(self):
        while True:
            grabbed,frame = self.Camera.read()
            frame = self.fgbg.apply(frame)

            if self.ShutdownVar ==1:
                break
            if self.STSP == 1:
                pic1, pic2 = map(np.copy,(frame,frame))
                pic1[pic1 > 126] = 255
                pic2[pic2 <250] = 0
                frame = pic1
            elif self.STSP ==1:
                time.sleep(1)
            cv2.imshow("Window",frame)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def MProcessing(self):
        Thread(target=self.Testpins,args=()).start()
        return self

    def BuildGUI(self):
        self.Abut = Button(self.TK,text = "Start/Stop System",command = self.CallbackSTSP)
        self.Bbut = Button(self.TK,text = "Change Pump Speed",command = self.CallbackShutdown)
        self.Cbut = Button(self.TK,text = "Shutdown System",command = self.callbackPumpSpeed)
        self.Dbut = Button(self.TK,text = "Start System",command = self.MProcessing)

        self.Abut.pack(padx=5,pady=10,side=RIGHT)
        self.Bbut.pack(padx=5,pady=10,side=RIGHT)
        self.Cbut.pack(padx=5,pady=10,side=RIGHT)
        self.Dbut.pack(padx=5,pady=10,side=RIGHT)
        Label(self.TK, text="Controller").pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
        mainloop()

    def CallbackSTSP(self):
        if self.STSP == 1:
            self.STSP = 0
            print("stop")
        elif self.STSP == 0:
            self.STSP = 1
            print("start")

    def CallbackShutdown(self):
        self.ShutdownVar = 1

    def callbackPumpSpeed(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GPIOControllersystem().BuildGUI()
```

Using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`, I can see that the connection between the raspberry pi camera and opencv is working through the bcm2835-v4l2 connection.
[image: Image of frame captured using system but plotting with matplotlib]

However when using opencv.imshow() the window result in a blackbox, nothing is displayed.
[image]

Update: so while testing I found out that when I perform the following task

```
import cv2
import matplotlib

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
grab,frame = camera.read()
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(frame)

grab,frame = camera.read()
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(frame)
```

update was solved and not related to the main problem. This was a buffering issue. Appears to have no correlation to cv2.imshow()

Comment: Have you checked that the VideoCapture of `frame` actually returns image data (skip the processing)? I guess that if you further minimize your code ([mcve]), it will help you in tracking down the root cause.. Good luck!

Comment: maybe you have to add cv2.waitKey(0) after  cv2.imshow("Window",frame). Hope this works.

Comment: Hello, I tried playing cv2.waitKey(0) into the code and it didn't fix the issue. I'm going to see if it might have to do with Spyder (as I use spyder for programming and editing)

Comment: guess how I fixed it. I added `cv2.waitKey(1)` after `cv2.imshow('Window",frame)`. After reading up, the `cv2.waitKey()` command is required to display an image. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a raspberry you should work with 
    from picamera import PiCamera
checkout [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) for that

Comment: These were the guides that I used to setup the raspberry pi initially and I used them to link opencv to python. Very helpful guides. Though most of the examples from pyimagesearch utilize the `picamera` module and from what I have read, this can eat up a lot of processing power especially when I plan to perform real time processing. I read that by keeping all acquisition in cv2, I can decrease the amount or processing power needed, hence why I went for cv2 connecting directly to the camera using the **bcm2835-v4l2** module.

Comment: interesting. I am on the same way. From the past I know that black Imshow was related to initiation failures.Did you try to save it as jpeg or avi ?

Comment: while messing with the code, I received this error **VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV**. I'm looking into it now but it is weird as V4L2 was originally supported by opencv.

Comment: ok good luck...will be interesting if you find it out and wonder why no one else is having that..